# Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm attempting to connect using Windows Remote Desktop Connection.

Can I make Remote Desktop Connection from other machines to Ubuntu 12.04 workstation?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking (at least for me). Are you looking for an application to install on the Ubuntu workstation? Or for applications to install on "other machines"? Also, there are many Remote Desktop alternatives: what are you looking for? VNC perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH you can do just about anything with the Linux shell.

If you really want to 'take over' your desktop, use something like VNC

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Here at Ask Ubuntu we try to post as many informative answers as possible, so can you please include an answer with instructions on exactly how to "use SSH" or "VNC"? You can always [edit] your answer by clicking the `edit` button right underneath the post.

Answer (score 0):

Remmina [supports RDP](http://www.remmina.org/wp/#features) (the Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol).

In addition it was voted the [winner of the 2016 TechRadar 7 best Linux remote desktop clients](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients-716346).

It also supports: VNC, NX, XDMCP, SSH and Telepathy.